# How can I delete linked tables in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I can't delete links to linked tables in Access 2007. I receive the following error:

> " is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

*Note that the quotation mark is part of the error message.*

The linked table name is `tblStudies`.

What can I do to get around this problem and be able to unlink (delete) linked tables?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that even the PATH that the source-table's database is in has no apostrophes!
No apostrophes in the path, none in the file name, none in the tablename.

I guess Access2007 simply doesn't like apostrophes!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well.

My Situation:

I had an access DB (MDB) that had link tables to a DB (source) that no longer existed.  Also, the source db had an apostrophe in its name.  Trying to delete the link gave the error specified in the question ('' is not a valid name...).

What I did:

- Created a new MDB with the same name as the old source db (since the source no longer existed)
  -Took the apostrophe out of the name
- Added tables that reflected the name of the one linked in the troublesome database (the one that won't let you delete the links)
- Went to the troublesome database and right clicked a linked table and selected Linked Table Manager.
  -Selected All and checked the box 'Always Prompt for New Location'

This asked me where it should look for the tables.

- Select the new db
- Make sure all tables are updated
- Go to troublesome database and right click and delete.

Some of these steps may be different from yours, depending on your exact situation.